# Showing $f/g$ is identically constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm been working on this problem:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are analytic and nonzero in $|z|<1$ and 
$$
\frac{f'(1/n)}{f(1/n)}=\frac{g'(1/n)}{g(1/n)} \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Show that $f/g$ is identically constant throughout $|z|<1$.

*Solution:* One way is to show that $(f'g-g'f)/g^2=(f/g)'\equiv 0$. However, I don't see anything. Also, it looks like  the Argument Principle. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track. The analytic function $f'g-fg'$ vanishes at all $1/n$, $n\in\Bbb N$, and hence is identically $0$ on the disk (by the Identity Principle).

Comment: Thanks, I thought apply the Identity Principle, but I didn't see it. Appreciate ^.^